# ¿Como Ingreso cadenas de texto a una lista enlazada sin que se repita? (C)

Tags: c, string, estructuras-de-datos

Necesito insertar una cadena de texto a una lista enlazada simple pero el ultimo dato que ingreso se repite en todo los nodos, si me pueden ayudar con algún ejemplo de como hacerlo,con todo dejo mi código.

```
nodo *insertarNodo(nodo *est, char *nom,float nota)
{
    
    nodo *nuevoEstudiante = NULL;

    nodo *aux = NULL;
    
    nuevoEstudiante = crearNodo(nuevoEstudiante,nom,nota);
    
    if(est == NULL)
    {
        est = nuevoEstudiante;
        printf("\n-Elemento Ingresado\n");
    }
    else
    {//Ingresa al final
        aux = est;
        while(aux->sig != NULL)
        {
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        aux->sig = nuevoEstudiante;
        printf("\n--Elemento Ingresado\n");
    }
    
    return est;
}

nodo *crearNodo(nodo *nuevoNodo,char *nom,float nota){


    nuevoNodo = NULL;
    
    nuevoNodo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    
    if(nuevoNodo != NULL)
    {
        nuevoNodo->nom_est = nom;
        nuevoNodo->nota = nota;
        nuevoNodo->sig = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nError al asignar memoría dinamica\n");
    }
    return nuevoNodo;
}

void pedirDatos(float *nota,char *nom){

    printf("\nINGRESE NOMBRE -> ");

    scanf("%s",nom);
    
    printf("\nINGRESE PROMEDIO -> ");
    scanf("%f",nota);
}


        void mostrarLista(nodo **est)
        {
          int cont = 0;
          nodo *aux = *est;
    
          if(*est != NULL)
          {
            printf("\nN O M B R E      N O T A\n");
            while(aux != NULL)
            {
              ++cont;
              printf("\n%d) %s         %f\n",cont,aux->nom_est,aux->nota);
              aux = aux->sig;
            }
          }
          else{
              printf("\nLista Vacia\n");
          }
        }
```

Implementación de las anteriores clases en el main

```
int main()
{
    int pos = 0;
    float nota = 0;
    char nom[CONST];
    char op;
    bool ext = false;
    nodo *estudiante = NULL;
    
    
    do
    {
        //strcpy(nom," ");
        system("cls");
        op = menu();
        switch (op)
        {
            case '1':
                pedirDatos(&nota,&nom[0]);
                estudiante = insertarNodo(estudiante,&nom[0],nota);
                system("pause");
                break;
            case '2':
                op = submenu();
                switch (op)
                {
                    case '1':
                        //buscar por nombre
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        printf("Ingrese Una Nota -> ");
                        scanf("%f",&nota);
                        buscarNota(&estudiante,nota);
                        system("pause");
                        break;  
                } 
                break;
            case '3':
                printf("Ingrese Posción de la lista -> ");
                scanf("%i",&pos);
                editarLista(&estudiante,pos);
                break;
            case '4':
                mostrarLista(&estudiante);
                system("pause");
                break;
            case '5':
                //eliminar datos
                break;
            case '6':
                //eliminar lista
                break;
            case '0':
                ext = true;
                printf("\nFIN DEL PROCESO\n");
                system("pause");
                break;
        }
    }while(ext != true);
    
    return 0;
}
```

ejemplo de salida por consola:

Ingreso de Datos:

Ingresar Nombre: **nom1**

Ingresar Promedio: **prom1**

Ingresar Nombre: **nom2**

Ingresar Promedio: **prom2**

Ingresar Nombre: **nom3**

Ingresar Promedio: **prom3**

Ingresar Nombre: **nom4**

Ingresar Promedio: **prom4**

Mostrar Lista

*Nombre   >>   Promedio*

nom4   >> prom1

nom4    >> prom2

nom4   >> prom3

nom4    >> prom4

Comment: Tienes que hacer un recorrido lineal e ir verificando si el *string* se encuentra en la lista. Todo esto se lo hace antes de insertar el elemento en la lista..

Comment: Lo que pasa es que ingreso varios datos y cuando mando a mostrar en la lista el ultimo que ingrese se repite en todos

Comment: El problema radica en que ningún momento retornas nada en la función `crearNodo`..

Comment: Gracias ese fue uno  de los errores, pero sigue con el mismo problema

Comment: ¿Cómo invocas a las funciones en el main?

Comment: No lo agregues en los comentarios. Edita la pregunta (con el botón `editar`) y añade el `main`..

Comment: `nuevoNodo->nota = nota` <-- `nota` es un *puntero*. La asignación copia el puntero, no la memoria a la que apunta. Deberías preguntarte a lo qué apunta, y qué pasa con esa memoria después.

Comment: Gracias amigos por sus comentarios me ayudaron mucho ya solucione el error estaba en la forma en la que guardaba el dato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error radicaba en que asignaba el valor de la siguiente manera:

```
nuevoNodo->nom_est = nom;
```

Esto copiaba en la dirección de memoria que almacenaba el puntero, y al agregar un usuario usaba la misma dirección del nombre en cada uno los nodos por lo que solo editaba el nombre y no agregaba un dato nuevo, La solución fue:

```
strcpy(nuevoNodo->nom_est,(nom));
```

en la siguiente función:

```
nodo *crearNodo(char *nom,float nota)
{   
    nodo *nuevoNodo = NULL;
    
    nuevoNodo = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    
    if(nuevoNodo != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(nuevoNodo->nom_est,(nom));
        nuevoNodo->nota = nota;
        nuevoNodo->sig = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nError al asignar memoría dinamica\n");
    }
    
    return nuevoNodo;
}
```